# Find (Beautiful Soup) returns None in case the tag is only one

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Could anyone help me please with understanding of this phenomenon? 'find' returns None in case the tag is only one. (I have already tried 'lxml', but it did not help). It is the part of what I am doing and receiving in my IDE:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Text documents\\for work\\English project\\chromedriver")
>>> driver.get('https://www.interactive-english.ru/uprazhneniya/408-conditionals-exercise/')
>>> content = driver.page_source
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
>>> FullList = soup.findAll(['ol', 'h4', 'h5']);
>>> htmlF = FullList[1]

>>> htmlF
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        Perhaps one day a cat will follow you home.<br />
        What would you do...
    </li>
    <li>
        Perhaps one day somebody will ask you to sing your favourite song.<br />
        What would you do...
    </li>
    <li>
        Perhaps one day you will find a hidden treasure.<br />
        What would you do...
    </li>
    <li>
        Perhaps one day somebody will throw an egg at you.<br />
        What would you do...
    </li>
    <li>
        Perhaps one day your car will be stolen.<br />
        What would you do...
    </li>
</ol>
```

```
>>> print(htmlF.find('li'))
<li>Perhaps one day a cat will follow you home.<br/>What would you do...</li>
>>> print(htmlF.find('ol'))
None
>>>
```

Comment: Show how htmlF is created. If it is soup object based on shown html I cannot repro this as works fine.

Comment: QHarr, thank you for the answer. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did

```
htmlF = FullList[1]
```

The top level retrieved is the `ol` tag. There are no nested `ol` within it which is why when you call `.find('ol')` on it you get `None`.

You can check with:

```
print(htmlF.name)  
>> 'ol'
```

You can do

```
htmlF.find('li')
```

for example to get first child as `li` are children within the parent `ol` you set `htmlF` to.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
FullList = soup.findAll(['ol', 'h4', 'h5']);
for fl in FullList:
    print(fl)
```

It finds all elements for me.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I do the same in my program, but also I have to check whether 'ol' is in fl. Probably, I should check whether 'ol' string is in str(fl).